# Two HTML headings - swap places in circles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swap

I have two headings/divs and I need to change places after 5 seconds in the way like on the picture. I tried some transitions and similar, but I have not find anywhere how to move elements in a circular way.

Moving of elements must be like "half circular". The example code is in the comments.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us your code what you have tried till now ?

Comment: Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/exc5m046/14/ Here is an example, but I do not know how to move them circular!

Comment: If you don´t have anything else to do, except to write these comments - please don´t do that! Nobody needs your additional spam, talking about what should somebody ask or write!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the headings inside a container. Using CSS animation you can rotate the container, and rotate the headings in the other direction. The animation is infinite, so the delay is in the animation itself.

Due to the delay, we can't simply reverse the `rotate` animation, and we need to add the reverse `rotateCounter` animation.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation: rotate 12s linear infinite;
}

.heading {
  position: absolute;
  animation: rotateCounter 12s linear infinite;
}

.heading1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.heading2 {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes rotate { 
  8% { transform: rotate(-180deg); } 
  50% { transform: rotate(-180deg); }
  58% { transform: rotate(-360deg); } 
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}

@keyframes rotateCounter { 
  8% { transform: rotate(180deg); } 
  50% { transform: rotate(180deg); }
  58% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="heading heading1">Heading 1</h2>
  <h2 class="heading heading2">Heading 2</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `setInterval()` function. And just like other said. If you still can't get it work. Please put your example code then we can help you.